# Need advice regarding traveling to UK and France

Tags: visas, uk, france, filipino-citizens, schengen-visas

I asked my father (British Citizen) if I could come to UK to visit him this coming Christmas, but he already made plans to travel to France. He did invite me along and told me to get a Schengen visa.

Sounds really appealing to me, but I’m not sure how do I apply for both visas. I’m Filipino and a student.

Do I apply for UK visa first, wait for the outcome, then apply for Schengen?

If my father is sponsoring me to get my UK visa, do we do the same process when I apply for my Schengen? Or I have to apply without sponsorship as I don’t have any relatives in France? If it’s the latter, is there a set amount of funds that I have to have when I apply for Schengen?

How do I provide proof of income if I’m a student and being financially supported by my parents? (Schengen)

My plan is to travel on 21 or 22 of December, first day of my university Christmas break, but my father’s flight to France  is already booked for the 24th. Is it going to be a problem if I arrive in the UK, leave 2 days after then come back to UK after 7 days?

I’ve read that I have to provide proof of booked flight return tickets with travel itinerary when applying for Schengen, how do I do it if I have to go via UK first?

Everything is so complicated in my head, I feel like I should just forget about it. Any advice to make this a little less difficult is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: If you are planning to travel to the UK first then go home to the Philippines from the UK you should apply for your UK visa first, https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa then (if successful) your Schengen visa. You would make flight reservations to France from the UK to support your French Schengen visa application. This answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing contains very helpful information regarding Schengen.

Comment: Thank you @Traveller. Will the French embassy not look at my application negatively because I’m applying from Manila but flying to France from and returning to UK? Should I explain it all on my itinerary?

Comment: Also, is UK Standard Visit Visa multiple entry? Will I not have any problem coming back to UK after arriving but leaving almost straightaway then coming back again? Is there a certain amount of day one must stay before leaving or am I overthinking it?

Comment: You will have to explain your travel plans by providing a detailed itinerary for both U.K. and Schengen. For your U.K. application, submit a travel itinerary including the proposed trip to France. If you get your UK visa, that should in theory be a positive when you apply for your Schengen visa. UK standard visitor visas are typically multi-entry, if you state your dates of entry in your application and itinerary you should not encounter a problem when you return from France.

Comment: Thanks again @Traveller. One more question, is Schengen Visa only granted on the dates mentioned on the itinerary?

Comment: See the answer here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77602/schengen-visa-for-leisure-purposes

Comment: Is your father a British Citizen “by descent” or “not by descent”? (That depends on whether he is British because he was born in the UK, or from British parents, or naturalised...). If he is British “not by descent” then you may be British as well, which may simplify things a lot. Check here: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen

Comment: I don’t think this applies to me @jcaron . He became a British citizen after I was born.

Comment: @itsmr, can you tell us what happened, if you applied for the Schengen visa as an answer, it would help people who see this question and have the same kind of question.

Comment: I applied for both UK and Schengen visas.

Comment: I followed @Traveller’s advice and applied for UK visa first. I included a detailed itinerary with my application including the trip to France and Croatia, a letter from University as proof that I’m a student and would be coming back to the Philippines, my father’s bank statements and a letter from him stating that he would financially support me while traveling. And I was granted a multiple entry UK visa!

Comment: After I received my passport with my UK visa, I proceeded applying for my Schengen visa. I used the same documents on my application. But because I was aiming to get a multiple entry visa to be able to fly to France and Croatia, my father wrote a letter with our detailed itinerary with proposed visit to Croatia, requesting a multiple entry visa if possible. And it was approved! It was amazing as it was my first application! And because my father is British my application was expedited as well.

Comment: So a massive THANK YOU! to everyone who helped and gave advise. I have been meaning to share what happened on here but University stuff got in the way. I have graduated now as well, with Latin honors. I am now currently busy looking for work. :)

Comment: @itsmr one reason for the issuing of the multiple Schengen Visa, is that it is a requirement of Croatia.

Answer (score 2):

> My plan is to travel on 21 or 22 of December, first day of my university Christmas break, but my father’s flight to France is already booked for the 24th. Is it going to be a problem if I arrive in the UK, leave 2 days after then come back to UK after 7 days?

No it won't be a problem, as long as you have the visas to cover this trip. You should therefore apply for both a UK visa and a Schengen visa. In addition, you need to be truthful and present a strong case. To do so, you typically need to include:

- a detailed itinerary including the trip to France and Croatia
- a letter from University as proof that you are a student and would be coming back to the Philippines,
- your father’s bank statements and a letter from him stating that he would financially support you while travelling

The purpose of these supporting documents is to demonstrate strong ties to your home country, the ability to support yourself during the trip, and the purpose of the trip.