# Schengen visa (main destination)

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm travelling to Hungary for a conference, which will last for five days, and then planning on visiting Italy for about a week and a half. My main purpose here is the conference (I got an invitation letter and all that) but my longest stay is in Italy, so I am not sure whether I should be applying at the Italian consulate or the Hungarian one.

Comment: If you arrive in Hungary for a well documented conference but with a visa issued by Italy, you'll have much more explaining to do than arriving with a visa issued by Hungary. Once in the Schengen area you have freedom to travel around. As for 'main destination' – would you be visiting Italy if you weren't attending the conference? Which of them is the "while I am here I might as well..."

Comment: Would you be travelling at all if it weren’t for the conference? Does this answer your question? [Schengen visa for leisure purposes after attending a conference](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77602/schengen-visa-for-leisure-purposes-after-attending-a-conference)

Comment: no the conference is the reason I am even visiting europe. thanks for the info, so hungarian consulate it is.